# How do i reuse a function several times on one page?

Tags: javascript, function

I would like to stop a function so it can run multiple times on one page. It is some radio buttons which i would like to be cleared if a checkbox is clicked. It should work with an infinite number of products. I'm the worst on javascript so i hope i could get an answer?

Sample:
 [image: See this image:]

```js
$('.product .question-input').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //radio is now checked
    $('.product .question-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
  return false;
});

$('.product .question-checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.product .question-input').prop('checked', false);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="product-title">Adobe</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-1">1
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-1" id="test-1" value="1"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-1">2
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-1" id="test-2" value="2"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-1">3
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-1" id="test-3" value="1"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-1">4
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-1" id="test-4" value="1"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-1">5
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-1" id="test-5" value="1"></label></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check text-center the-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" class="form-check-input question-checkbox" id="check-1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-1">I don't use this product for work</label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="product-title">Mocups</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-2">1
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-2" id="test-1" value="1"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-2">2
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-2" id="test-2" value="2"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-2">3
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-2" id="test-3" value="1"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-2">4
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-2" id="test-4" value="1"></label></div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="test-2">5
        <input class="form-check-input question-input" type="radio" name="test-2" id="test-5" value="1"></label></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check text-center the-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" class="form-check-input question-checkbox" id="check-1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="check-1">I don't use this product for work</label>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I the only one that sees the first paragraph repeated like 4 times?

Comment: Yes yes yes yes :)

Comment: Sorry, fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

By passing a *reference* to a handler instead of directly passing the handler function:

```js
function handler() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.product .question-input').prop('checked', false);
  }
  return false;
}

$('.product .question-input').change(handler);

$('.product .question-checkbox').change(handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not to this with the same class names for every group, you need to separate the classes in html and create functions for each of them like this:

```
$('.product1 .question-checkbox1').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.product1 .question-input1').prop('checked', false);
  }
  return false;
});
```

end then product2, product3...